# Change object field using a hook

Tags: reactjs

I want to change a certain value in an object.
I'm trying to do this using a hook.
If I enter the name attribute directly, it works. But not if I want to read it out from an event
In addition, the hook must be executed directly.
What happens at this point only after another call. So the value is always the previous one

```
function updateFrageBogen(e, wert) {

 let feldName = e.target.id;
 //feldName IS NOT NULL ("name").
 let aendereWert = !wert;

 //******* WHY Not Work: feldName is declared but its value is never read.
 setUser({ ...user, feldName: aendereWert });

 //That is how it goes
 setUser({ ...user, name: aendereWert })

 console.log(user);

 }
```

Comment: i think in your console.log(user) you need to use console.log(user.feldName) to read feldName

Comment: In `setUser({ ...user, feldName: aendereWert });` I suspect `feldName` is not a getting assigned with the value. In other words, you are storing `feldName` inside the `user` that is `user.feldName`.  If this is the case you either need to form the object before setting it to state. For example, `const newUser = { ...user }; newUser[fieldName] = fieldValue; setUser(newUser);`